# HTML body not scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll

Look at the following CSS script.

```
body {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

I found the above solution to scroll the body of a HTML page. But it does not working for me. So how can I fix this. Please help me !

Comment: What is your content? We need more information for this.

Comment: A `body` creates scrollbars automatically as long as the content height is big enough. Do provide more information.

Comment: It not makes scrollbars when the content is so big.

Comment: Maybe the content is position: absolute, or fixed?

Answer (score 1):

To set `height: 100%` you need to have a parent with a fixed `height`, example

```
div {
  height: 50px;
}

div span {
  height: 100%; // 50px
}
```

So, in this case, if you're trying to set the body's height the same height of the screen you can use `height: 100vh` that's 100% of viewport

this way, I think the scroll wil work properly

Comment: I tried also using  "height: 100vh". But same problem there.

Comment: your content is bigger than the screen?

Comment: Yeah, it is a big content

Comment: To make sure, open the inspector (preferably on Chrome), and on tab Elements, hover the elements around the body, and make sure it is bigger than the screen, and the content is bigger than the body, sometimes `float: left`and `display: block` in some elements can solution the problem of no or wrong height

Sorry for the many questions, but you aren't providing so many informations